# (Magento 1.9.3.3) Cannot send a customer data to the Magento server

Tags: c#, magento, magento-1.9

I'm developing a C# Winapp for connecting Magento to create customer data using SOAP API V2 and encountered an error [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJr7L.jpg) when my program is trying to send a customer data to the Magento server.

It works fine if I send it with `http` but it won't work with `https` and I need to use `https`. How to make it work?

Here's my code for sending data:

```
PortTypeClient mservice = new PortTypeClient();
var mlogin = mservice.login("User", "apikey");

int newCustomerCreateID = 0;
filters myfilter = new filters();

// Create Customer
customerCustomerEntityToCreate customerCreate = new customerCustomerEntityToCreate();

//fill attributes
customerCreate.email = SessionStore.getEmail();
customerCreate.telephone = Int32.Parse(SessionStore.getTel());
customerCreate.password = SessionStore.getTel();
customerCreate.firstname = SessionStore.getFName();
customerCreate.lastname = SessionStore.getLName();
customerCreate.middlename = "";
customerCreate.id_card = Int32.Parse(SessionStore.getIdCard());
customerCreate.store_id = 1;
customerCreate.store_idSpecified = true;
customerCreate.website_id = 1;
customerCreate.website_idSpecified = true;
customerCreate.group_id = 1;
customerCreate.group_idSpecified = true;
//customerCreate.suffix = "P";
customerCreate.prefix = SessionStore.getPrefix();
customerCreate.dob = SessionStore.getBdate();
//customerCreate.taxvat = "123456";
customerCreate.gender = Int32.Parse(SessionStore.getGenderNum()); //1-Male;2-Female
customerCreate.genderSpecified = true;

newCustomerCreateID = mservice.customerCustomerCreate(mlogin, customerCreate);
mservice.endSession(mlogin);
```

Comment: What happens when you open your WSDL url manually? Is the WSDL properly formatted?

Comment: When I opened WSDL url manually from Google Chrome, it redirects me to the company's homepage.

Comment: I'm assuming it redirects you to http version? Check your base uri under `System -> Configuration -> Web`. Basically your shop should render valid wsdl when you manually open the url.